# parsing the output of a command with a complex path in batch

Tags: batch-file, windows-8

I have a Windows 8 batch file where I'm trying to parse the output of a command to set a variable. The following works fine if the path in`set frob=c:\path_to_frob\frob.exe` contains no spaces:

```
for /f "tokens=5" %%i in ('%frob% -l ^| findstr "flux capacitor at "') do (
    if NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
        set flux_level=%%i
        set /A flux_level=!flux_level:4,1!
    )
)
```

But, if `frob.exe` is located at `set frob=c:\path to frob\frob.exe` then I get the error:

`'c:\path' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I've tried modifying the for loop with `usebackq`, but I get the same error:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=4" %%i in ('"%frob%" -l ^| findstr "flux capacitor at "') do (
```

How do I get `for /f` to parse the output of a command with a complex path?

**EDIT 1**

This command:

```
for /F "tokens=4" %%i in ('"%frob%" -l ^| findstr /C:"flux capacitor at "') do (
```

expands to this:

```
for /F "tokens=4" %i in ('"c:\path to frob\frob.exe" -l | findstr /C:"flux capacitor at "') do (
'c:\path' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

**EDIT 2**

I can verify the `%frob%` path is correct by putting:
`"%frob%" --help`
Just before the `for /f` loop. It works as expected and prints the application command-line help.

**EDIT 3**

If my `findstr` string is shorter and does not require quotes, then I don't get that error. For example, this command:

`for /F "tokens=4" %%i in ('"%frob%" -l ^| findstr flux') do (`

doesn't give me the error about frob's path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=4" %%i in ('"%frob%" -l ^| findstr /c:"flux capacitor at "') do (
        set "flux_level=%%i"
        set /A "flux_level=!flux_level:4,1!"
)
```

- If `%frob%` contains spaces, quote it
- a `findstr` command to search a string with spaces inside needs the search term indicated as `/c:"..."`
- The commands executed in the `in` clause run in another `cmd` instance and the errorlevel is not accesible inside the `do` clause. If nothing is found, there will be no lines in the output of the pipe and the `for` will not execute the code in the `do` clause.

**EDIT 1** - `for` command executes the command indicated in the `in` clause in a separate `cmd` instance. This instance retrieves, parses and executes the command. In some cases, the double quotes interfere, the initial and last quotes are removed (see `cmd /?` for more information) and the final command is wrong.

```
for /f "tokens=4" %%i in ('
    " "%frob%" -l | findstr /c:"flux capacitor at " "
') do (
        set "flux_level=%%i"
        set /A "flux_level=!flux_level:4,1!"
)
```

Quote the full inner command in double quotes and remove the `^` in the pipe to handle the parse problem in the subshell

Comment: I've applied those changes, but I still get the original error. I appreciate the tip about the errorlevel, though.

Comment: @PaulH, Which of them? The `not recognized` one or the `cannot find the file` one?

Comment: `'c:\path' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: @PaulH, if all the quotes (single and double) are at the correct place, the only way to get this error that i see is if the `%frob%` file does not exist.

Comment: So weird! But you nailed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `usebackq` which changes the meanings of the different types of quotes.

The `"quotes around the full program path and name"` are required to escape the space-separators. the `'quotes round the command'` are used to tell `for /f` that the string is a command to be executed. You'd probably get the same results *using* `usebackq` by using backticks (<kbd>`</kbd>) in place of single-quotes.

---

There's something mighty wrong here.

I've tried the following:

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "frob=u:\sourcedir\another dir\showparams.exe"
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('echo. ^|"%frob%" -l ') do (
 ECHO %%i
)
ECHO ===============
SET "frob=u:\sourcedir\another dir\showparams.exe"
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in (`echo. ^|"%frob%" -l `) do (
 ECHO %%i
)
ECHO ===============
FOR %%w IN ("%frob%") DO (
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('echo. ^|%%~dpnxsw -l ') do (
 ECHO %%i
)
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Three different ways of executing a program located in a path containing spaces.

All worked perfectly - provided the file nominated as `fob` existed. Strangely, I received the same response as OP if the executable was missing :O

Obviously I don't have the OP's executable, but the method worked quite happily for me. I suspect an error in the value of `frob`.

Comment: Okay, I tried `for /f "tokens=4" %%i in (`"%frob%" -l ^| findstr "flux capacitor at"`) do (` and I get the error `The system cannot find the file `"c:\path to frob\frob.exe".`